# Can't search for strings within hidden files with fzf's Rg command in vim

Tags: search, bash, plugin-fzf

I just installed [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) for my bash terminal and the fzf.vim plugin for vim. I've placed the following code at the bottom of my .bashrc script:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='rg --files --hidden --no-ignore-vcs'
export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS='-m --height 50% --border'
```

When I am in `vim`, I can use `:FZF` to search for hidden files. However, if I use the fzf.vim's `:Rg` command, it will not search for strings *within* any hidden files since it uses the regular ripgrep command, which by default, ignores hidden files.

I can search for strings within hidden files while in the terminal:

```
rg --hidden 'search_string'
```

How can I do the same thing while I'm in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late but I had this issue as well. As you're using fzf.vim you can configure the Rg command as per their instructions by adding the following to your `init.vim` file and adding in the `--hidden` option.

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Rg
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(
  \   'rg --hidden --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case -- '.shellescape(<q-args>), 1,
  \   fzf#vim#with_preview(), <bang>0)
```

Taken from https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#example-rg-command-with-preview-window

You might need to tweak this a bit if you want it displayed differently.